# Javascript drawImage(...) not drawing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm having problems dynamically loading images in my canvas. My Asp.Net codebehind sends the ImageLink via

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "upd",
         "<script language='javascript'>loadTempAnalyze('"+ imageLink+"') </script>", false);
```

to the client. The code for drawing the image in my canvas is:

```
function loadTempAnalyze(imgLink) {
console.log(imgLink);
var mcv = window.document.getElementById("thermCanvas");
var cont = mcv.getContext("2d");
var img = window.document.getElementById("mImg");
img.onload = function () {
    console.log("imageload");
    imgComplete(img, cont, mcv);
    console.log("image draw");
};
img.src = imgLink;
}
function imgComplete(img, cont, mcv) {
    console.log("img call");
    window.document.getElementById("imgHeader").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    mcv.width = img.width;// + "px";
    mcv.height = img.height;//+ "px";
    cont.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    };
}
```

The link displayed by `imgLink` is valid, there are no exceptions appear in Firefox's Console, but nothing is displayed in the Canvas. The logs seem to be ok first "http://localhost/images/p1.png", then "imageload", "img call" and "image draw" at last. The img Image displays the image as expected.

The strange behaviour I noticed, is that if I hardcode imgLink in html, everything works fine.

`<canvas id="thermCanvas" onload="loadTempAnalyze('http://localhost/images/p1.png')/>`

The URL I'm using to access the site is `http://localhost/mainPage.aspx`.

Comment: Notice, that you're lacking a `'` here: `"url('" + img.src + ")"`.

Comment: Somehow this line worked with the typo and after I corrected it the main problem still exists. -thanks anyway ;) ... I'll correct it in my question too, because it doesn't change the main problem behaviour.

Comment: How big is the image? Is there any reason you draw it at coords 10,10 ?

Comment: 1040 x 840 , and about 300kb